# How can i avoid duplicate same post in wp?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

I m working on a wp plugin and i have 3 tables. In my plugin i have two different loop: both of them create programmatically a page from my tables. My problem is that if i refresh the page, it duplicate my pages. How can i avoid this? I have tried with get post title but it not work. Here my loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($namepages); $i++) {
    mic_create_new_page($name[$i],$namepages[$i]);     
}

foreach ( $resu as $res ) {
    $id = $res->id;
    $keyword = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$res->keyword));
    $secteur = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$res->libelle)); 
    mic_create_new_page_key_sec($keyword, $secteur, $id);
}
```

and that s my functions

```
function mic_create_new_page_key_sec($keyword, $secteur, $id) {
    global $user_ID;

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => ucfirst($keyword) . " " . ucfirst($secteur),
            'post_content' => '[makeitseo-keyword-secteur]',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_name' => $keyword ."-".$secteur."-k".$id
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
function mic_create_new_page($name, $namepages) {
    global $user_ID;

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => 'Services ' . $name,
            'post_content' => '[makeitseo-keyword]',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_name' => $namepages
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add one time a new page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371992/how-to-add-one-time-a-new-page)

Comment: Non, cause i need a page creation for every time a new value is added in my table...You know what i mean?

Comment: This sounds more like a PHP programming question. You need to add some code to say 'only add the new values', or do something like mark them in your source data every time they are successfully added and you'll have to figure out how to write that in PHP

Comment: what do you think if i stock all posts of my site in array and in the moment i call the function, i match the page that will be insert and the page that are in the array? If it s not in the array, so go with the function...

Comment: Yes, exactly, something like this. Try to choose a field to check they are the same that is easy to match and will be identical **but unique** across all the posts. I'd suggest try to write it - if you have a question about how to use Wordpress specific functions post it here, or if you have a question that is about logic and PHP programming or databases put it in stackoverflow

Comment: thank you, i fixed the problem ;)